# CORS supported & dockerized web server

Tags: http, docker, cors

Given an API server with Swagger UI, I want to run this server in a docker container and access from outside world and make sure this server supports CORS.

Note that current server implementation set response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <request.origin>` if any `Origin` request header exists, otherwise it is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

So, I dockerized this server and it is running on default docker interface, `0.0.0.0`. On localhost or any other deployment environment, api is fine through cURL, postman etc. don't make any trouble.

When I access this dockerized server from a browser to use Swagger UI, I see errors indicating OPTIONS request wasn't successful. Unlike CLI tools, browsers send `OPTIONS` request before actual one. After checking developer console, I see that I get `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.`

I also see that `Origin` and `Host` request headers are different and I believe it leads to this error. For example, `Origin` is `http://localhost:8080` and `Host` is `0.0.0.0:8080` due to docker. CORS reference's [relevant part](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-security) also mention this. I guess modern browsers implement CORS check per this reference.

I can get rid of this by setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header for all requests but that is only a work-around and not secure.

Appreciate any guide and help.

Comment: Did you try setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <request.host>` to validate your suspicion about `Origin` & `Host` mismatch issue?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Since host `0.0.0.0` corresponds to all addresses, I used `*` as value of  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Answer (score 1):

OK, a few things:

1. The `Origin` is what indicates to the server that it's a CORS request - if the `Origin` request header is not passed, it's not a cross-origin request, so you don't need to send **any** CORS response headers.
2. Sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <value-of-Origin-request-header>` (what you say you're doing) is **absolutely** the correct thing to do. You could add code to only send the ACAO header if the `Origin` request header is one you trust, but that may be getting too complex at this point.
3. The value of the `Host` header should be immaterial - as long as you send back the value of the `Origin` header in the ACAO header, it should work.
4. If you're passing cookies with your request, you'll also need to return `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`, otherwise any Set-Cookie response headers will not be processed by a browser.

To the main problem  (I think) - supporting OTPIONS requests:

You are correct that browsers may send a CORS preflight OPTIONS request, whereas non-browsers do not. If so, you'll need to do the following:

- Ensure your server supports OPTIONS requests (by default, many web servers only support GET, POST and HEAD out of the box)
- Return the exact same ACAO header with the response to that OPTIONS request also
- Handle the other CORS request headers that get passed with the preflight OPTIONS requests - `Access-Control-Request-Method` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers`.

That last bit can get tricky, but the simplest thing to do is to return the following response headers to the OPTIONS request:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <value-of-Origin-request-header>`
`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`
`Access-Control-Allow-Method: <value-of-Access-Control-Request-Method-request-header>`
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: <value-of-Access-Control-Request-Headers-request-header>`

and return the following response headers with the main GET/POST request:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <value-of-Origin-request-header>`
`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up with setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.